# Herança de Form abstrato

Tags: c#, winforms, classes-abstratas

Tenho um Form padrão, com um `textbox`, um botão pesquisar e um grid; como pretendo usar ele para diversas pesquisas, deixei um método abstrato Pesquisar() e ao mesmo tempo o form como abstrato...
Ao herdar esse form, implemento no form filho o metodo Pesquisar() que funciona normalmente em execução, porém este form filho não é carregado pelo designer do visual studio e retorna o seguinte erro:

> O designer deve fazer uma instância do tipo 'FormPesquisa`2[[FormFilho
>   System.Retaguarda.Model, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null], mas ele não pode porque o tipo foi declarado
>   como abstrato.

Comment: Deixa apenas o método como abstrato

Answer (score 1, accepted):

não declare o form como abstrato, porque ele deve ser instanciado!

deixe o método como:

```
public virtual void Pesquisar()
{
throw new NotImplementedException("Método pesquisar não foi implementado");
}
```

e nos filhos:

```
public override void Pesquisar()
{
//implementação
}
```

Comment: Excelente ideia, mas será que existe alguma forma de a IDE avisar em tempo de desenvolvimento para implementar o método? Pra não acontecer de "esquecer" de implementar e acabar passando..

Comment: aí acredito que não... eu fiz uma vez um software, onde todas as classes herdavam a partir de uma, que eu chamava de Core, e nela havia um método "GetDataSet", nas classes você pode usar interfaces que vão alertar para uma não implementação na hora de compilar, e no form de pesquisa, o objeto, que era do tipo Core, apenas chamava o metodo getDataset e preenchia o grid view, bastava eu informar qual classe iria passar para o form de pesquisa, utilizando o polimorfismo